# EF 4.1 How to merge a graph returned by web service into an existing context

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-4.1

I have a scenario where I need to merge in a large graph (over 2000 entities) returned by web service into existing DbContext. So, my first try:

```
    ' get new object from web service
    Dim newCust = DAL.GetCustomer(ActiveCustomerView.CustomerID)

    ' attach the object graph into existing context
    context.Customers.Attach(newCust)
```

This create duplicate conflicts in case I try to attach objects containing entities that already exists in the context.

To avoid this problem I’m clearing the local data and then call AcceptAllChanges before attach:

```
        context.Orders.Local.Clear()
        context.OrderItems.Local.Clear()
        context.Messages.Local.Clear()
        context.Contacts.Local.Clear()
        context.Parcels.Local.Clear()
        context.CustomerTransactions.Local.Clear()
        context.ReturnedParcels.Local.Clear()
        context.ReturnedOrderItems.Local.Clear()
        context.InventoryItems.Local.Clear()
        context.Shippments.Local.Clear()
        context.Prints.Local.Clear()

        DirectCast(context, IObjectContextAdapter).ObjectContext().AcceptAllChanges()
```

This works but the performance is not acceptable as it takes over 40 sec to clear the data.

Is there any other way to effectively accomplish that?
Can I dispose somehow DbSet's instate of clearing them?

I can’t destroy and create new context each time I need to attach the graph because it contains other objects that would get lost.

Comment: What about disposing current context and using a new one?

Comment: If the data received from the web service is much greater than the data you are already holding, would it be better to inverse the above?  Create a new context, attach the web service data, use that context as a starting point (i.e. then merge the existing data after duplicate checks?)

Comment: When you say "merge the existing data", do you mean to use attach function? If yes than I don’t see how this would work. Attaching an object also attach all related objects. This means I would have to clear most of the data from old context anyway and I would end up in the same point.